# Change the value of a column based on the content type

Tags: 2010, list, content-type

Just wondering if there's an OOTB way to do this:

I've got a list which has two content types (<sub><sup>Apples and Oranges</sup></sub>).
If an Apple item is created, I'd like the Type field to be set to Apple, and Orange if an Orange item is created.

I've tried setting a default value to unique field for each of those content types, and was planning on creating a calculated field based off those fields, but they aren't available to use in the calculation.

Any ideas how this can be achieved without custom code or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a New Item workflow that will set the field Type to the value of Content Type when the item is initially created.